# Electric dipole (E1) transition why do we assume $I$ remains constant?

Tags: atomic-physics, radiation

I have been looking at the selection rules for electric dipole transitions with the presence of hyperfine structure.The once of importance for this question are:
$$\Delta F=0,\pm 1 \text{ (not $0\rightarrow 0$)}$$
$$\Delta J=0,\pm 1 \text{ (not $0\rightarrow 0$)}$$
The fact that we do not allow $0\rightarrow 0$ for the value of $J$ indicates that we are requiring the value of $J$  to change in such a E1 transition. This means that we assume no transitions where only $I$ changes occur, and from what I can tell we see $I$ as remaining constant in such a transition. Why is such an approximation valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum numbers $I$ and $J$ belong to different subsystems of the atom: $I$ is the nuclear spin QN, and $J$ is total electronic angular momentum QN. 
Therefore changes in $J$ would be associated with electric field influencing the electron cloud, and change in $I$ would imply change in the state of nucleus.

Now take a look at the electric dipole moment operator $\hat{d} = q\hat{r}$.
For a nucleus that is typically several orders of magnitude smaller than electron orbits you would expect the same to be true for transition electric dipole moments. 
Therefore the transitions where $I$ changes would be much weaker than electronic transitions, and for most practical applications you can assume that only $I$ preserving transitions take place.

Another reason why said approximation holds well for optical transitions is the difference in energy scales for electronic and nuclear transitions - the energy of an optical range photon is simply not sufficient to induce change in the state of nucleus.